# How to restore a wallet with 24 words and passphrase?

Tags: wallet, bip39, ledger

The BIP39 standard supports an optional passphrase.
Cold wallets such as Ledger wallet support this feature, so you can have your private key additionally to 24 words secured with passphrase.

At this moment there is no option to restore such wallets neither through Yoroi or Deadalus wallets.

How to software recover such a wallet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By April 2021, there is no software solution for Cardano wallets that supports such combination.

There is an open source [tool](https://github.com/iancoleman/bip39) (and its [extended fork](https://github.com/Coinomi/bip39-coinomi)) on the Github to convert such mnemonics.
It supports most of the wallets, **unfortunately it does not support Cardano** logic yet.

The only way to restore such a wallet is to use any physical cold wallets that fully have implemented BIP39 support.

Answer (score 8):

The wallets support "hidden" wallets on hardware devices with passphrases but you can't restore the wallet directly into Daedalus or Yoroi. Instead, you need to restore the wallet to a new Ledger device and then connect it to the software
wallet.

Comment: And once restored, you can happily move your funds elsewhere, if you desire to abandon the Ledger platform.